# What is wrong - google - SPLIT_BUNDLE 15

Tags: react-native, admob

I have a problem with "Invalid Data Safety Form".

I received an information:
"SPLIT_BUNDLE 15: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: App Activity Data Type - Apps On Device".

The app is a TODO list. It only shows AdMob ads. It does not collect data from users.
Due to the fact that google is introducing consent to display ads to users from the EEA and Great Britain by the end of the year, I have set "Approximate location", "Application activity - Interactions with the application" and "Device identifiers and other" in the security form.
I am using the React Native Google Mobile Ads package.

Maybe someone has a similar problem?